# What media player can I use to play 4K YouTube videos (steam video)

Tags: youtube, smplayer, 4k-monitor

I'm trying to play YouTube videos in SMPlayer and VLC player. How do I get 4K to play?

With SMPlayer I can only play 1080p at 60fps. VLC player can only do 720p at 30fps.

- Lubuntu 64-bit.
- Intel Q6600, Geforce 1030,
- 4Gb RAM

How can I stream 4K at 60FPS YouTube video through SMPlayer?

Comment: VLC does 1080p just fine for me. Run VLC from the command line so you see the output (VLC <path to file>), is it using hardware decoding ?

Answer (score 2):

SMPlayer has supported 2K and 4K YouTube streaming already for some time. So this question is probably solved now.

[image: SMPlayer preferences dialogue]